# How to share global variables between Celery's Periodic function and a Python's function

Tags: python, celery, pymongo

I am using Celery's periodic function to do batch updates of my database. The data to be inserted is stored in a global list by some other function of the same script. The problem is, whenever the Periodic function executes, it see the list as an empty one.

Following is the code snippet for the same:

```
client    = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
db        = client.module_data
batchData = []


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name='Batch_Update')
def batchUpdate():
    global batchData
    print batchData
    if len(batchData)>0:
        db.logs.insert_many([_data for _data in batchData])

def writeLog(event='', method='', execution_time=0.0):

    global batchData

    if event=='' or method=='' or execution_time==0.0:
        return

    _date = datetime.now()
    _data = {'event':event, 'method':method, 'execution_time':execution_time, 'date':_date}

    #db.logs.insert(_data)
    batchData.append(_data)
    print batchData
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use your backend. As I can see it's mongo. Store data to the mongodb when you are doing `writeLog` and read it in your `batchUpdate`.
Please pay attention to nature of the data you want to store. It likely should be serializeable as [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle) or json.